# Track specific email from wordpress/woocommerce in Mandrill

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce, mandrill

I have already added a tag in Mandrill but I cannot seem to figure out how I can track specific emails which are sent from Wordpress and Woocommerce. In this case I want to add a unique tag to all emails for subscription renewal reminders.

Is this possible and how do I go about this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you'll probably want to make a filter for those emails in your theme functions file. You can read more about that and see some examples on the Mandrill blog here:http://blog.mandrill.com/own-your-wordpress-email-with-mandrill.html

Some plugins/addons will have auto tags added because wpMandrill tries to detect the process that generated the email, but not all will have it.

If changing up/adding the PHP isn't something you want to do, you could also use the [Rules Engine](http://help.mandrill.com/forums/22087471-Rules-Engine) to auto-apply a tag based on the subject line or sender for those emails.